# How Same-origin policy works?

Tags: w3c, same-origin-policy

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy , browsers restrict the resources access within the same origin. However, I think almost every website has something like:

```
<script src="http://partner.googleadservices.com/gpt/pubads_impl_79.js" async=""></script>
```

And the src here is an external resource. Does it violate the Same-origin policy?

Comment: You can't load a resource from a different origin (host / port) via AJAX. Script tags are fine to load from different origins. That's how JSONP works.

Comment: I see. Thanks, @bash0r !

Comment: Script tag is special in a sense that it can execute cross domain calls. But Developers can not retrieve its content.

Comment: @blindProgrammer With JSONP you can. (See the link in my updated answer).

Comment: @bash0r Yes you can. You can not retrieve "innerHTML" as text directly from script tag. What you can do is to send "function call" to script tag. For example, if i send myFunc("my Data"); into script tag and then if i have declaration of that function: myFunction(data){alert(data);} myFunction gets executed right away and you have access to data parameter, in our case: "my Data"

Comment: @blindProgrammer Ah yeah. The innerHTML is not accessible as you said. :) Sorry for confusing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same origin policy affects the so called AJAX-requests. It has nothing to do with script tags. A script tag can load resources from different origins. To clarify origin a bit more: If the host (e.g. www.google.com) or the port (e.g. 80) differs, it's not the same origin. JSONP (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) abuses script tags to work around the same origin policy. So it does not violate against the same origin policy.

Answer (score 4):

Let us assume that partener.googleadservices.com as site B and some website of yours say www.foobar.com as site B
For requests other than GET (like POST, PUT etc.,) and GET that has custom headers, browsers sends a pre-flight request to B (HTTP OPTIONS) with Origin Header containing the value of Site A. Site B could then verify this value and respond back with Access-Control-Allow-Origin header (It could as well simply pass '*' to indicate allow all websites).
If the value of Access-Control-Allow-Origin does not contain Site A, then browsers that respect the CORS policy simply blocks the request.

For your query about `<script>` tag, I've observed that Site A sends a GET request. Hence, the browser is not obliged to block access to Site B in this case since it is not GET and also doesn't send any custom headers. You could open the Inspect mode in chrome browser and observer the calls being made.

Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#How_CORS_works for more details